# replace dynamically created div/stop running page that was loaded in the previous div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page1 that was loaded dynamically using javascript, on that page I have a setTimeout that checks every 5 seconds for new messages, the problem that happens is that if there is a new message it should replace the div with page2, completely closing the page1 but unfortunately the timer on page1 remains working even with page2 replacing the old div, how should i close the connection with page1 so that the timer stops running while page2 is on the div?

Page1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function carregapagina($pagina){
            $.ajax({
                url: $pagina,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: "",
                success: function(content){
                    $("#DisplayDiv").html(content);
                }  
            });
        }

        function atualizadados(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({        
                    dataType: 'json',   
                    url: 'comando.txt',
                    success: function(data){
                        switch (data.comando){
                            case "teste1":
                                carregapagina('page2.php');
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                setTimeout('atualizadados()', 5000);
            });
        }

        atualizadados();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="DisplayDiv">
    <?php echo 'PAGINA 1 carregada com sucesso!'; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page2

```
<?php

echo '<h1>PAGINA 2 carregada com sucesso!</h1>';

?>
```

comando.txt

```
{"comando":"teste1"}
```

Comment: i dont see your timer which execute every 20 sec?  setTimeout is not setInterval

Comment: sorry, updated question, setTimeout is 5 seconds, setTimeout('atualizadados()', 5000);

Comment: but setTimeout is not repetitive ?  it just wait 5 sec before executing the action

Comment: yes but i need it to stop when page2 loads

Comment: `clearTimeout`OR`clearInterval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to trap in variable the timeout:

```
    switch (data.comando){
                        case "teste1":
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                            carregapagina('page2.php');
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            var timer = setTimeout('atualizadados()', 5000);
```